# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.ts(7017) typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-react

I'm creating an input handleChange but getting an error *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.ts(7017)* when trying to update the state(this.setState). here is the code snipet

```js
const [first_name, setFname] = useState<string>();
  const [last_name, setLname] = useState<string>();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>();
  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState();
  
   const handleChange = (e:any) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    };
```

Comment: From the error message, it seems like this code is at global scope...? But hooks are for use within components, not at global scope. Can you provide more context for what you're doing and where/how you're running this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem is this:

```js
this.setState({ [name]: value });
```

That looks like code meant to be in a `class` component, but you only use hooks in functional components (or other hooks), not `class` components. With functional components and hooks, you don't use a central `setState` method, you use the setters you get from `useState` instead.

Also, the error message indicates that TypeScript things that code is at global scope, which is odd because again, you don't use hooks there.

Finally, TypeScript should be complaining about your `useState` calls, since you've used `string` as the generic type parameter but haven't provided any initial value. The initial value will default to `undefined`, which isn't a string.

---

It's a bit tangential, but what the error is specifically saying is that the type of `this` in that code (`typeof globalThis`) doesn't have a `setState` property defined on it, so `this.setState` implicitly has the `any` type because TypeScript has no type information for it. You're using it as a function, so TypeScript is warning you that it doesn't have anything telling it that `this.setState` is a function.